# input jTextFields dissapear after showing a Jlabel over it.

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I created an application and made a simple gui using the guy swing builder of Netbeans. 
I created a jtextfield and a jlabel. The jlabel is placed over the jtextfield but is not visible at the start.

this is my problem. When I run my application I can enter text in the jtextfield. This works without a problem. After that I activate my jlabel with a button. The jlabel shows up (on top of the jtextfield as I wanted). When I deactivate the jlabel it disappears, but my input text has also disapeared. In fact its hidden, because when I select the jtextfield again parts of the text start to appear again. Also when I start to write text again in the jtextfield all my previous text shows up again.

Is there some way to update the fields again or something to show them whenever I make a jlabel appear/dissapear over my jtextfields? or is this some kinds of bug?

I didnt provide a code for this, because there is no advanced programming involved in the simple program i created.

I hope someone can solve this problem for me.

Comment: You will need to provide a runnable example of the problem before we can properly diagnose it

Comment: Why are you covering a jtextfield with a jlabel? What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps you can accomplish something similar (making text invisible) by making the foreground and background color identical...

Comment: Instead of overlaying the components you could consider swapping them, or using a `CardLayout`. I do not provide any code for this, because there is no advanced programming involved in that solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already solved the problem myself. 
Seemed that my textfields where not layered correctly ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use

```
JFrame.validate();
```

to refresh your UI after you removed the JLabel, then it should display the JTextField correctly...

If that doesn't work you can also try:

JPanel.setVisible(false);

JPanel.setVisible(true);

(Assuming you are using a JPanel in your program) 
This also refreshes your UI

However it would be much simpler if you added your code so we could see what you may be doing incorrect